# How can I add several columns within a dataframe (broadcasting)?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[30, 19, 6], [12, 23, 14], [8, 18, 20]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index = ['A', 'B', 'C'], columns = ['Bulgary', 'Robbery', 'Car Theft'])
df
```

I get the following:

|  | Bulgary | Robbery | Car Theft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 19 | 6 |
| B | 12 | 23 | 14 |
| C | 8 | 18 | 20 |

I would like to assign:

```
df['Total'] = df['Bulgary'] + df['Robbery'] + df['Car Theft']
```

But does this operation have to be done manually? I am looking for a function that can handle conveniently.

```
#pseudocode
#df['Total'] = df.Some_Column_Adding_Function([0:3])
#df['Total'] == df['Bulgary'] + df['Robbery'] + df['Car Theft'] returns True
```

2. Similarly, how do I add across rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum`:

```py
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Or if you want subset of columns:

```py
df['Total'] = df[df.columns[0:3]].sum(axis=1)
# or df['Total'] = df[['Bulgary', 'Robbery', 'Car Theft']].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: nit: can simplify `df[df.columns[0:3]]` to `df.iloc[:, :3]`

Comment: This is what I did for rows: ```df.loc['Total'] = df.loc[df.index[0:3]].sum(axis=0)``` Is your code a better convention to use ```df.iloc[:3, :]```?